# "Congratulations Jon Skeet, and thanks a million! »" banner refuses to die

Tags: support, homepage

Every time I visit a Stack Overflow page I am presented with a "Congratulations Jon Skeet, and thanks a million! »" banner:

[image]

And with all scripts disabled:

[image]

I've seen it before so I click the <kbd>X</kbd> button on the right and the banner goes away.

But it refuses to die! Next time I visit Stack Overflow it comes back from the dead - just like a zombie - and I'm not referring to the cocktail.

Disabling all scripts makes no difference.

Please make it go away. I don't want to keep reading it - once is enough!

Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 57.0.4

Comment: That screenshot is not how Stack Overflow looks for me. Which userscripts/plugins affecting SO are you using?

Comment: Jon Skeet jokes became real. I warned you.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I've added another image. Disabling all scripts makes no difference.

Comment: It is rigged to show up exactly one million times. How many times have you seen it?

Comment: @usr2564301 lol :)

Comment: @usr2564301 It's rigged to show for one more time for every point of rep Jon gains :)

Comment: Doesn't appear for me.

Comment: Probably you can make a script to disable it?

Comment: Legend says if you click the `x` one million times the banner goes away forever.

Comment: Excepting Jon Skeet to come and give an answer to this problem.

Comment: Not familiar with Firefox, but what does the icon mean to the left of the URL, the one with the warning triangle on it?

Comment: @DavidG It means that the site uses an HTTPS connection, but loads some content via HTTP from other sites

Comment: @TuringTux Yeah, that's what I guessed. I don't see tht problem here so it must be something specific to OP. It means there's something peculiar going on there.

Comment: wait for the "two million" banner. Should come at some point.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth The change to the topbar is as a result of [Top-navigation choices](https://stackapps.com/questions/7603/top-navigation-choices), a userscript I wrote, which allows you to customize how the topbar is displayed and have something that's consistent across all SE sites. I'm not aware of it having any impact on the issue in this question.

Comment: @DavidG That was a temporary glitch. It is no longer happening and it doesn't affect the issue.

Comment: I had this issue last week. It's gone away now though.

Comment: Update your Firefox... I don't think it will fix this issue. Just a free advice

Comment: @Sankar Erm 57.0.4 is the latest release version.

Comment: Have you tried downvoting Jon to under a million rep points?

Comment: Did you try turning it off and on again?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid My browser and scripts? Yes.

Comment: No the banner :).

Comment: Do you have cookies set to remove all cookies on closing FireFox?

Comment: It does not disable because Jon Steek deserve so much respect.

Comment: @TT. No. I do have 3rd party cookies disabled on some sites.

Comment: You clicking the X button but you doing it without respect

Comment: I think Chuck Norris turned his banner off. But it involved a roundhouse kick

Comment: Is your browser configured to clear the cache each time? This might be the issue. Otherwise, you could be pragmatic and just ignore it until it goes away.

Comment: @AndyG No. And yes, I'm ignoring it :)

Comment: [ If I had such an extraordinary profile I would want the banner to stay there permanently ;) ]

Comment: Wait for the 10-years-on-SO banner - it will stay for 10 years.

Comment: Looks like Jon Skeet finally went full Skynet, he now has control of all computers. The message is not directed at you its acknowledging Jon Skeet as your pc.

Comment: It might be a technical issue only Jon Skeet can solve the issue. By the way, I want to see that banner for the whole day just for Jon Skeet.

Comment: larrymacbarry is right. You're not clicking hard enough

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev how in the world would that help? you would just get busted for serial downvoting...

Comment: Just guessing: Maybe the banner appears every time Jon Skeet makes a new million in reputation.

Comment: If pure `Java` `click()` is not working Selenium guys must be knowing `JavaScript` `click()` to force a click happen :)

Comment: What is the value of your `notice-jon` cookie on SO.com?  The X button sets the cookie which is then read and synched across your sessions via Redis.  I don't see any value for your account in Redis suspect the cookie is either missing or unparsable.

Comment: @BrianNickel Ha. That could be it. I don't have that cookie. FF was set to allow only first party cookies from stackoverflow.com. Allowed third party and all is well :)

Comment: It will go away when people stop posting "bugs" about the display of Jon's user info card.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Double-check that Firefox is not disabling cookies from the site, or that you aren't refusing them through a Firefox third-party plugin. It has nothing to do with enabling or disabling JavaScript, even if you are logged in or not. Apparently Stack Overflow checks to see the status of a cookie to see if the banner "dismiss" button has been clicked. Removing this cookie will re-enable the banner. See for yourself, and check other browsers to verify this.

Notice the date of the expiration. In my case, I dismissed it on the 22nd, the cookie expires in two days, which is probably when Stack Overflow will disable the banners from popping up.

[image]

Comment: I don't have that cookie. FF was set to allow only first party cookies from stackoverflow.com. Allowed third party and all is well :)

Comment: I dismissed the banner on an earlier day, and my cookie would still expire on January 24th. When I first read this question, I actually tried deleting that cookie to test it. The notification did not reappear.